# Vuetify - How would you embed a 'Select' component within a Header/text tag?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-select

I'm a backend developer doing front-end work so bear with me.

Imagine a big header at the top of a web page:

Below is the list of stock available to ↓**users-dropdown**↓

If you clicked the ↓**users-dropdown**↓ , it would have a list of users and upon selecting a user in the drop-down, it would do some stuff (not important). The important thing here is that the dropdown is coupled to the text. I guess the text is pre-appended on the left of the Select component.

For example, it could read

- Below is the list of stock available to ↓John↓
- Below is the list of stock available to ↓Pete↓
- etc

Hopefully, I've made some sense but probably not. Thought I'd reach out online to see if anyone has come across this UX requirement before I tackle it myself tomorrow (don't you love engineering, always problems to solve). Not sure if you can embed a select component within text or if you need to tightly wrap everything in a v-col.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `display: inline-block` with CSS to place a block element (like the `v-select` normally is) inline with text. Take care as this may increase line height. Vuetify has the `d-inline-block` utility class for this, which is fine if you don't need many other CSS adjustments (it also automatically overcomes any selectivity or deep selector issues that may occur when overriding styles normally).

Alternatively, you could use the prepend slot in v-select via `<template #prepend></template>` and place your text prefix there.